# SSH - Alterar o caminho default da sessão

Tags: linux, ssh

Como faço para iniciar minha sessão SSH numa pasta específica, ao invés de ir para ~/ (/home/nome_usuario/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, para fazer isso é muito simples:

Abra um terminal e digite:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Abra e adicione ao final desse arquivo o caminho para o seu diretório de preferência dentro de um comando `cd`:

```
cd /caminho/para/o/seu/diretorio/favorito
```

Valeuu, aqui funcionou perfeitamente (Fedora 20)!

Comment: Perfeito! Vlw @bruno-casali .